# How to Change path to a report in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, report

I work on two computers(database,forms,reports) and I added report but when I move the Project to the other computer and I try to activate the reports it shows an error. The error says that the path to the report wasn't found and it shows me the path of the computer I created the reports. when I click on a report I see in the properties the path of the computer I'm using so I guess there is an other path to the reports and I need to change it. what to do?

edit:
the name of the reportWizard is `Citys.rdlc` and the name of the form which I show the report is `CityReport.cs`

In the properties window of the report under `Misk/FullPath:C:\Users\computer1\Desktop\New folder\Work\Work\Reports\Citys.rdlc`

The error when I try to open the report :

> An error occurred during local report proccessing. The report
>   definition for report
>   'C:\Users\Computer2\Desktop\work\work\Reports\Citys.rdlc'. Could not
>   find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\Computer2\Desktop\work\work\Reports\Citys.rdlc'.

Comment: I suppose your report file is in a sub folder of the exe file folder, such as: `Reports\...` so you should point to that path as relative or using Application.StartupPath to get the current application path.

Comment: by the way, it also depends on your kind of report. If using local report, I think there is no need to do so.

Comment: Can you show the line of code where you get the path from? Is it hardcoded as a `const` in your code or is it relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is add a Application configuration file to your project and specify the `path` in that file and slightly change your code to access the path from this file. just google `using App.config in c#`  you will find enough information.

once that is done just change the path, when running on different computer, in the  app.config file and use it on any computer you want

Comment: I don't think this can help, in fact the path of his report file is fixed and relative to the project path.

Comment: can you post the exception that you are getting so that we have a better idea as to what might be happening

Comment: There Isn't an other way for changing the path of the report...I know there is a toolbar of the dataset but I cant find it...I'm sure that the way to change the path is there